# How can I cancel and progress report a task that returned by WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync method?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I'm learning task-parallel-library. I have some old code that use WebClient class to download data from web. I want to convert my previous code that using [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern(EAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

My old code were below:

```
WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
client1.DownloadDataCompleted += (o, e)=>
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        //code that update UI report download has been canceled.
    }
    else
    {
        byte[] s = e.Result;
        //code that update UI report downloads has been completed.
    }
};

client1.DownloadProgressChanged += ( o,  e) =>
{
    //code that update UI report downloading progress.
    updateProgress(e.ProgressPercentage);
};

//start download asynchronous
client1.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/"));

//code to cancel download.
client1.CancelAsync();
```

Now using Task API, I had code:

```
WebClient client2 = new WebClient();
Task<byte[]> task = client2.DownloadDataTaskAsync("http://stackoverflow.com/");

task.ContinueWith((antecedent) =>
{
    byte[] s = antecedent.Result;
    //code that updateUI report download has been completed.
});

//TODO how to code that can cancel the download and report progress?
```

So My questions are:

When using the task method DownloadDataTaskAsync, does the WebClient class has build-in api that I can cancel the download and report the download progress?

Comment: Related: [MSDN - WebClient.DownloadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloaddatacompleted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can extend WebClient:

```
public static class WebClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<byte[]> DownloadDataTaskAsync(this WebClient webClient, string address, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        using (cancellationToken.Register(webClient.CancelAsync))
        {
            return await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(address);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call the extension method:

```
var data = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync("http://stackoverflow.com/", cancellationToken);
```

Comment: usually you will want to wrap your registration in a `using` block so it gets unregistered once you leave the block. Nothing else needs to change just throw a `using` in and put the `return await obj...` inside the block.

Comment: I agree. Disposable objects should be disposed. I've added a using block.

Answer (score 0):

There are no overloads that support cancellation so you can't cancel that async action (You may want to read [How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx)).

You can however add a timeout or cancellation on top of that action that will let your code flow proceed.
For progress reporting you might want to look at [WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It seems to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static async Task<byte[]> DownloadDataTaskAsync(this WebClient obj, Uri address, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        var task = obj.DownloadDataTaskAsync(address);

        using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
        {
            if (task != await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task))
            {
                throw new OperationCanceledException(cancellationToken);
            }
        }

        return await task;
    }
```

Modified version from @Dartal

Use task completion source to solve the problem, or you can reference [How do I cancel non-cancelable async operations?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx)

Then, you can use CancelAsync to force close the connection

[Aborting a WebClient.DownloadFileAsync operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10332506/aborting-a-webclient-downloadfileasync-operation)